# selenium geckodriver error with firefox

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
While launching firefox browserin eclipse i am getting an error as mentioned below Usage:
```

E:\new gecko\geckodriver.exe [OPTIONS]
    E:\new gecko\geckodriver.exe: Unknown option --port=30415
    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:30415 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
    Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:00:17 -0800'
    System info: host: 'KIREETI-PC', ip: '192.168.43.138', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
    Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:91)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:244)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:121)
        at sriram.main(sriram.java:17)
    Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:30415 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:142)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:88)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:296)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:113)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
        ... 7 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:74)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
        ... 22 more

Comment: Could you share Selenium, browser and driver versions

Comment: thank krishna Reddy

Comment: i am unable to fill the text field for hidden field the html content             
 <input name="input" value="" type="text">
<input name="input-fossil" value="string"type="hidden">

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using driver of specific browser, you can use "Webdrivermanager" plugin in maven, so it will resolve most of problems related to browser and its instance.
Even this help me lot to overcome browser related problems.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using all the latest versions of driver executable file(geckodriver.exe), Selenium server standalone jar (3.14.0) and Firefox browser. I was not facing any issues.